# How to add dynamic labels along the prev/next arrows in Swiper?

Tags: swiper.js

You've seen this on other sliders, where along with the nav arrows you'd have some label/title indicating the contents of the next/previous slide.

Hopefully someone has already done this, so I can copy and adapt the code. Failing that I guess I'll experiment with different events listeners, pulling the text from sibling slides, and changing the content of active slide's nav divs.

Though maybe it's better to save the label text as data attributes? I don't know. Just brainstorming the approach here...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Instead of tracking the active slide, I'm adding labels when the swiper is initialised. Sharing it here, in case anyone here has a similar question.

```
let homeSwiper = new Swiper('.home-swiper', {
      loop: true,
      navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
      },
      on: {
        init: function () {
          addLabels();
        },
      },
    });
```

Each slide has a hidden span that I use as its label. I then just pull those labels from the surrounding slides:

```
  function addLabels() {
    let homeSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.home-slider .swiper-slide');
    homeSlides.forEach((slide, i) => {
      let labelPrev, labelNext;

      if (i === 0) {
        labelPrev = homeSlides[homeSlides.length - 1].querySelector('span.label').textContent;
        labelNext = homeSlides[i + 1].querySelector('span.label').textContent;
      } else if (i === homeSlides.length - 1) {
        labelPrev = homeSlides[i - 1].querySelector('span.label').textContent;
        labelNext = homeSlides[0].querySelector('span.label').textContent;
      } else {
        labelPrev = homeSlides[i - 1].querySelector('span.label').textContent;
        labelNext = homeSlides[i + 1].querySelector('span.label').textContent;
      }
      slide.querySelector('.slide-nav-label--prev').textContent = labelPrev;
      slide.querySelector('.slide-nav-label--next').textContent = labelNext;
    })
  }
```

Comment: So, are the Next/Prev buttons included with each slide? I thought they were outside of the slides and you would have to update them each time the current slide changes. Isn't that the case?

Comment: The Next Prev are outside the .swiper-wrapper, but inside the .swiper-container. I'm not using them, for anything other than navigation. I am using a hidden element to provide a label/name for each slide (WP, ACF). I use the textContent from that element to pupulate labels, which I absolute position near the prev/next buttons. The labels themselves are nit clickable. .... Though now I have to debug, b/c sometimes my prev next label names are the same (inaccurately labelling the prev/next slide)

Comment: I see... I did something similar where I am updating a Span inside the Next/Prev Buttons. I had the same issue where at a point in time, due to the duplication of slides that Swiper does to facilitate the infinite loop, your next and previous slides are technically the same. I added an if, in the function I use to retrieve the Next label, and I check whether the current ActiveIndex is equal to the last slide index, and if it is true I use the slide with index = 1 as Next.